# JavaScript file API to node.js how to send ArrayBuffer with data through websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, buffer, fileapi

Hi I'm trying to send and upload a file from JavaScript client to node.js server, and it actually works, client:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost");
ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
//file input code, it all works etc...
loader.onload = (e) {
   ws.send(e.target.result); //actually works and sends the arraybuffer
}
loader.readAsArrayBuffer(file/*not quoted here but you get the idea*/)
```

the server side isn't important just basic websocket server, that DOES in fact receive the arraybuffer (in the form of buffer).

The problem:
I need to also send the file **name** along with the data, how can I add a file header to the ArrayBuffer on the client side, and read it in node?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: @dansalias I thinki I ended up opening a new socket for each file uploading, and first sending the string as the name, then listen on the server side for the next message to be an arraybuffer, then link the strink and the arraybuffer, or as other answers said I could have combined the name into the buffer in a custom file format, with a header etc and then read the frist few bytes on the server side to extract the name and get the rest of it by copying the remainder of the arraybuffer

Answer (score 0):

can you just wrap the ArrayBuffer in an object with the file name or metadata?
i.e.

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost");
ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer";

// the object to be passed by the socket
var filePayload = {
    fileName:'file.file',
    fileType:'xxx'
    // any othere metadata here
};

//file input code, it all works etc...
loader.onload = (e) => {
    // add the array buffer as a property in the object
    filePayload['data'] = e.target.result;
    ws.send(filePayload); 
}
loader.readAsArrayBuffer(file/*not quoted here but you get the idea*/)
```

Comment: seemingly if I send a JSON object directly without stringifying it, then I get this result on the server:  [object Object], I'm using the nodejs "npm install ws" library, I guess they do .toString() for everything they receive, do you have the same result?

Comment: @bluejayke in that case you can stringify the JSON first before sending it through the socket and parse the JSON string on your server

Comment: The JSON doesn't stringify with pure binary data, try it, the binar-data property is just an empty object, the only way to do it is to convert the binary data to something liek a uint8array, stringify it, then on the server, parse it, and covnert it back into a BUffer, which kind of defeats the whole point of binary since its a lot slower